# Seperate matching values in array to new array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array of days and times that I need to separate into matching days coordinating with times. I have tried intersect associative and other array functions but cant seem to find one that does this. Has anyone had to of done this before?

```
Array
(
[Monday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 5:00 pm
    )

[Tuesday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 5:00 pm
    )

[Wednesday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 3:00 pm
    )

[Thursday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 2:00 pm
    )

[Friday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 2:00 pm
    )

[Saturday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 5:00 pm
    )

)
```

I need to grab all the days that have the same open and close times and put them in their own arrays like:

```
Array
(
[Monday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 5:00 pm
    )

[Tuesday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 5:00 pm
    )


[Saturday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 5:00 pm
    )

)


Array
(
[Wednesday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 3:00 pm
    )
)


Array{
[Thursday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 2:00 pm
    )

[Friday] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9:00 am
        [1] => 2:00 pm
    )
)
```

Comment: You would make an array of Start and Close times and match them with days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply using a `foreach` loop, Like following:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($a as $k => $value) {

    // create a unique key from times values
    $key = join($value);

    // if the key isn't already existing, we create a new array with this key
    if( !isset( $result[$key] ) ) {

        $result[$key] = [];

    }

    $result[$key][$k] = $value;

}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Try it here: [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a92fbf4ec33553e7a6220622d73ef91940b85a70)

Comment: Brilliant, quick solution. This can be used for a lot of issues like this. Thanks!